# Glyphicon not displaying in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: html, prestashop-1.6, glyphicons

I am working on a prestashop module and I am trying to use a Boostrap glyphicon as a button in my template, but it does not work and I can not figure out why.

```
<td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></span>
    </button>
</td>
```

My column stays empty, prestashop documentation shows this example but it it does not work either

```
<div class="form-group has-warning">
    <label class="control-label" for="input1">Label with warning</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback"></span>
</div>
```

Is it something to add to prestashop ? Did I miss something ?

Comment: Where do you want to use this FrontOffice/BackOffice? What kind of button do you want to make (as an appearance)?

Comment: @PrestaShop-Developer.com It is for BackOffice, it will be a button to import a product, appearance is not very important, so the cloud-download glyphicon would be perfect.

Comment: The solution is in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the button you need, for example if it's a "panel-footer" button you can use:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" name="submitTest"><i class="process-icon-download"></i> Download</button>
```

or for link button:

```
<a href="#" title="Download" class="btn btn-default">
    <i class="icon-cloud-download"></i> Download
</a>
```

Comment: Your first suggestion works perfectly thank you !
But why is it not working when I replace "process-icon-download" by "glyphicon-cloud-download" ?

Comment: Because there's no such CSS class defined at the PrestaShop BackOffice styles.

Answer (score 1):

In the default-bootstrap theme, prestashop doesn't use exactly the classical bootstrap glyphicon classes but some custom one.

In your example you can use

```
<td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        <span class="icon icon-cloud-download"></span>
    </button>
</td>
```

To resume you have just to replace glyphicon by icon.

Good Luck